# Конструктор перемещения

Tags: c++, c++11

Зачем нужен конструктор перемещения, если есть оператор перемещения:

```
operator=(T&&)
```

Comment: А как тогда перемещать объект при передаче в функцию?

Comment: Это вопрос? Когда в качестве аргумента передается `const Type&` (еще возможна ситуация с `Type x = y`, так называемая, copy-initialization). [Здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206359/in-which-situations-is-the-c-copy-constructor-called) можно прочитать подробнее

Comment: @soon тогда вызывается копирующий конструктор

Comment: Да, вызывается. Я отвечал на ваш комментарий "когда вызывается копирующий конструктор"

Comment: @VladD пример обявления: A& operator=( A&& a);

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Область использования**

*Конструктор и оператор перемещения* используются компилятором в разных ситуациях:

- *конструктор перемещения* применяется в местах, где объявление совпадает с определением (инициализацией) *rvalue-ссылкой* на экземпляр этого же класса, либо посредством `direct initialization` в конструкторе класса/структуры (если же определение произойдет с помощью *lvalue-ссылки*, то вызовется *конструктор копирования*);
- *оператор перемещения* применяется в местах, где экземпляр класса уже был ранее определен и к нему применяется `operator =`, который в качестве аргумента приминает *rvalue-ссылку* на экземпляр этого же класса (если же оператор принимает *lvalue-ссылку* , то вызовется *оператор присваивания*).

Про `rvalue-ссылки` можете почитать [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/226229/), [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/242639/) и [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/157961/).

---

**Контрольный пример** (для разъяснения отличия в работе данных конструкций)

```
#include <vector>

class Buffer
{
public:
    Buffer(const std::string& buff)
    :   pBuff(nullptr)
    ,   buffSize(buff.length())
    {
        pBuff = new char[buffSize];
        memcpy(pBuff, buff.c_str(), buffSize);
    }

    ~Buffer(){ destroy(); }

    Buffer(const Buffer& other)
    :   pBuff(nullptr)
    ,   buffSize(other.buffSize)
    {
        pBuff = new char[buffSize];
        memcpy(pBuff, other.pBuff, buffSize);
    }

    Buffer& operator=(const Buffer& other)
    {
        destroy();
        buffSize = other.buffSize;
        pBuff = new char[buffSize];
        memcpy(pBuff, other.pBuff, buffSize);
        return *this;
    }

    Buffer(Buffer&& tmp)
    :   pBuff(tmp.pBuff)
    ,   buffSize(tmp.buffSize)
    {
        tmp.pBuff = nullptr;
    }

    Buffer& operator=(Buffer&& tmp)
    {
        destroy();
        buffSize = tmp.buffSize;
        pBuff = tmp.pBuff;
        tmp.pBuff = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    void destroy()
    {
        if (pBuff)
            delete[] pBuff;
    }

    char* pBuff;
    size_t buffSize;
};

Buffer CreateBuffer(const std::string& buff)
{
    Buffer retBuff(buff);
    return retBuff;
}

int main()
{
    Buffer buffer1 = CreateBuffer("123"); // срабатывает конструктор перемещения
    Buffer buffer2 = buffer1;             // срабатывает конструктор копирования
    buffer2 = CreateBuffer("123");        // срабатывает конструктор перемещения, затем оператор перемещения
    buffer2 = buffer1;                    // срабатывает оператор присваивания
}
```

---

**Дополнение**

В C++11 каждый класс, помимо конструктора по умолчанию, имеет следующие 5 дефолтных операций:

1. конструктор копирования (copy constructor);
2. оператор присваивания (copy assignment);
3. конструктор перемещения (move constructor);
4. оператор перемещения (move assignment);
5. деструктор (destructor).

При определении одной из этих 5-ти операций рекомендуется явно указать (либо определить, либо объявить с помощью `default` или `delete`) все остальные, т.к. все эти 5 операций тесно связаны. Это будет способствовать лучшему пониманию семантики класса при чтении кода. 
Если явно определена одна из упомянутых 5-ти операций (в том числе с использованием `default` или `delete`), то:

- недостающие операции копирования будут определены автоматически с
  поведением по умолчанию;
- недостающие операции перемещения определены не будут.

Это следует учитывать при написании классов.

Answer (score 18):

Вопрос фактически звучит как "зачем вообще нужны конструкторы". Вопрос в принципе не относится к "перемещениям", а фактически сводится к принципиальной разнице между конструкторами (копирования, перемещения, и т.д.) и другими функциями-членами класса (операторы присваивания и т.д.)

Конструктор в общем случае работает на "сыром" (несконструированном, непроинициализорованном) блоке памяти. В момент начала работы конструктора объекта как такового еще не существует и он не имеет никакого предсказуемого состояния. Соответственно работа конструктора сводится к созданию/инициализации нового объекта в предоставленном блоке "сырой" памяти. Конструктор копирования, например, копирует это состояние из некоего объекта-образца, конструктор перемещения - перемещает, конструктор преобразования - преобразует и т.д. Конструктор перемещения никоим образом не выделяется из этого ряда.

Оператор присваивания же всегда имеет дело с уже проинициализированным/сконструированным объектом, находящимся в некоем предсказуемом "валидном" состоянии. Работа оператора присваивания сводится к освобождению исходного состояния объекта (освобождению ресурсов, например), за которым следует копирование (или перемещение, или преобразование и т.п.) нового состояния из некоего объекта-источника.

Вот собственно и все. Т.е. операторы присваивания в общем случае делают больше работы, чем конструкторы. Операторы присваивания уничтожают старое состояние объекта и создают новое. А конструкторам уничтожать нечего - они только создают новое состояние.

В рамках этой логики как конструктор перемещения, так и перемещающий оператор присваивания никак из общего ряда не выделяются. Поэтому не ясно, откуда вообще мог возникнуть вопрос вроде "Зачем нужен конструктор перемещения, если есть оператор перемещения?".

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, стандартная реализация оператора присваивания могла бы делать следующее: для объекта в левой части оператора присваивания вызвать сначала деструктор, а потом конструктор копирования, передав ему ссылку на объект в правой части. Наверное, это было бы лучше, чем просто копировать все поля из правого объекта в левый, но всё равно это было бы не совсем правильно. Дело в том, что при копировании объекта требуется выделить новый ресурс, но потенциально это может закончиться неудачей. Если это произойдёт, то после неудачной попытки присваивания объект в левой части останется в некорректном состоянии: старый ресурс уже освобождён (вызван деструктор), а новый захватить не получилось. Поэтому при перегрузке оператора присваивания нужно всегда сначала захватывать новый ресурс, и только если эта операция прошла успешно, освобождать старый, заменяя его новым (по этой причине оператор присваивания в принятом ответе написан не совсем правильно). В случае перемещения, в принципе, такой проблемы нет: копируется только ссылка на ресурс, и старый ресурс, которым владел объект в левой части оператора перемещения, может быть освобождён безболезненно, как до копирования ссылки, так и после. Скорее всего, аналогичное копированию разделение на конструктор и оператор в случае перемещения сделано для случая, когда неудачей закончилось освобождение ресурса в левой части оператора перемещения. В этой ситуации необходимо, чтобы объект в правой части продолжал владеть ресурсом. Таким образом сохраняется атомарность копирования и перемещения: либо нам удалось полностью создать копию объекта или полностью переместить ресурс из одного объекта в другой, либо копирование / перемещение прошло неудачно, и ни один из объектов не был изменён.