# l-value и r-value ссылки с++

Tags: c++, ссылки

просматривая стандарт, я заметил что в нем различают l-value и r-value ссылки, в отличие от тех же указателей например. Почему так? И что такое r-value ссылка, я просто так и не понял.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Копирование и перемещение (семантика перемещения в С++)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/849809), [Конструктор перемещения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/490753), [Как устроена семантика перемещения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/989707).

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Что значит двойной амперсанд (&&) в параметрах функции и как его использовать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/512284), [Rvalue переменная](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/352192), [What does T&& (double ampersand) mean in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5481539).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Наиболее важной особенностью С++11, вероятно, является семантика перемещения, а основой семантики перемещения является отличие rvаluе-выражений от lvаluе-выра­жений.
>
> Полезной эвристикой для выяснения, является ли выражение lvalue, является ответ на вопрос, можно ли получить его адрес. Если можно, то обычно это lvalue. Если нет, это обычно rvalue.
>
> <sup>(Из книги "Эффективный и современный С++. 42 рекомендации по использованию С++11 и С++14" Скотта Мейерса)</sup>

lvalue сокращенно от left-value, a rvalue - right-value. Пример:

```
 var = true;
```

`var` - lvalue(занимает какое-то идентифицируемое место в памяти т.е. имеет адрес, можно также изменять), `true` - rvalue. В общем, rvalue-выражения временны и недолговечны(область видимости выражения), в то время как lvalue живут дольше, поскольку существуют как переменные. Но если использовать rvalue ссылки, можно добится расширения области видимости.

Ссылки бывают rvalue(`&&`) так и lvalue(`&`):

```
Class& lvalue = obj;
Class&& rvalue = obj;
```

Стоит заметить, что можно сделать так:

```
 Class&& rvalue = Class();
```

Что не сделаешь для обычних ссылок. Rvalue ссылка ведет себя точно так же, как и lvalue ссылка, за исключением того, что она может быть связана с временным объектом, тогда как lvalue связать с временным (не константным) объектом нельзя.

Comment: Не стыдно книгу Мейерса плагиатить?

Comment: Сразу видно, читали...

Comment: Если чесно, то не очень стыдно. Так как я люблю скотта и собираюсь купить себе ещё его совершенные книги

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я не читал, не ужели слово в слово переписано? Если да, надо, наверное, хотя бы ссылочку оставить.

Comment: Спасибо за правку

Comment: @ТарасПрогер Всегда пожалуйста. Если копипастите что-то в ответ (в том числе если оригинал на английском, а вы засунули его в переводчик), источник [обязательно указывайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).